# SVN did not performed merge

Tags: svn, merge, diff, conflict

Currently i am facing an issue with SVN and merging a file between trunk and a project branch.

In trunk i have a file e.g A.java with the Revision 100 which is the newest version of the file. 
In my project branch which is regularly synchronized with trunk i have the same file which remains in Revision 50. There were at least 4 changes for that file done (e.g in Revision 60 / 70 / 80 / 90) but it looks like SVN is not merging this file for what ever reason. If i am doing a svn diff for these files it sees differences but if i am doing the merge it doesn't.

I looked already in the svn info / mergeinfo of that file but can't explain my self how this is happening. I also don't know if this is happening also for some other files.

my question is now:
- How do i resolve the issue best (just doing a manually update of the file in my project branch)
- How can i find the reason for that issue?
- How can i find files which maybe also be impacted?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Yes I'd just manually merge the files and check in the result on the desired branch.

Comment: Do you have any idea why this happens?